# Yadcf Cannot read property 'element' of undefined whith filter_type date or range_date

Tags: datatables, yadcf

I have the following code

```
{
    column_number: 2,
    filter_type: 'date',
    date_format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
},
```

And in HTML I have `<td>21/03/2015</td>`

jQueryUI datepicker works in this column, but when date is selected I get
**Cannot read property 'element' of undefined**
and page refreshes.

This problem appears with filter_type: date and range_date.
What could be the problem? Other filters work fine.

Comment: So I found a problem. It is a conflict with this plugin http://keith-wood.name/uidatepickervalidation.html. I have to use its validation option for other date pickers on the website. Disabling it yadcf date picker works fine.

Comment: Is it possible to make two plugins to work together?

Answer (score 0):

Disabling **jQuery UI Datepicker Validation** wasn't an option. The only solution I found is to wrap `<table>` inside `<form>` element since **jQuery UI Datepicker Validation** only works when date picker input is inside `<form>`. And since Yadcf filters input are not inside form element there was an error thrown. But I think that it is not a good practice to have table inside

`<form action="#"><table id="datatable"></table></form>`

Comment: Since *jQuery UI Datepicker Validation* requires that the date inputs will be present inside a form in order to validate them, I don't see anything wrong in placing that table inside a form, but If you really want to avoid wrapping the table inside the form you can place the filters outside the table (by using `filter_container_id`)